# What's wrong with my SQL query ?? It won't fetch data

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm basically trying to fetch the next three future events including today from the database m below is my query and it says that derived tables must have an alias , I'm new to this .. what would be the fix ?

```
select * from events where event_start_date in
   (select event_start_date from
          (select distinct event_start_date from events
                  where event_start_date >= '2014-05-02' order by event_start_date)
    WHERE rownum <= 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "derived tables must have an alias"

That error means that when you use a subquery in the `FROM` clause, it's called a *derived table* and you must declare an alias for that.

Here's a simpler form of your query that should work:

```
SELECT events.* FROM events
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT event_start_date FROM events
      WHERE event_start_date >= '2014-05-02'
      ORDER BY event_start_date LIMIT 3) AS d USING (event_start_date)
```

I provided an alias for the derived table where you see `AS d`. It doesn't matter what you choose as the alias, it just has to have one.

> "Unknown column 'rownum' in 'where clause'"

`ROWNUM` is an Oracle-specific feature that automatically provides an imaginary column to every result set, with an integer corresponding to the row number of that result set. But this is not standard SQL, and MySQL doesn't support it.

So I removed the reference to the implicit `ROWNUM` column, and replaced it with a `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: would that work to fetch the next three coming dates including today's date ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a column named `rownum`:

```
select * from events where event_start_date in
  (select distinct event_start_date
  from events
  where event_start_date >= '2014-05-02' AND rownum <= 3
  order by event_start_date) T
```

**EDIT:**

If you are trying something like `rownum` as in oracle, you can use `LIMIT`:

```
select * from events where event_start_date in
  (select distinct event_start_date
  from events
  where event_start_date >= '2014-05-02'
  order by event_start_date
  LIMIT 3) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 3 total queries, you can do this by JOINing. Look into JOINs to see how you can join across the columns you wish to JOIN on from each table.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @JoshMein I thought about it. However, if I was to re-write the query using JOINs I'd be doing his work for him. From the question it seemed to me like he didn't know about JOINs.

Comment: Then post this as a comment. It doesnt really answer the question.

Comment: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from events where event_start_date in
   (select event_start_date from
          (select distinct event_start_date,rownum from events
                  where event_start_date >= '2014-05-02' order by event_start_date) as t1
    WHERE rownum <= 3)
```

This will help you.

Comment: it shows this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as t2' at line 5